# Thermistor, Wait until GPIO is High in Windows 10 IoT

Tags: windows-iot

I am porting an example of Python to C#, and as I see in the original code

[thermistor example](http://raspberrypi.powersbrewery.com/project-8-temperature-sensing-thermistor/)

[image]

There is a wait like:

```
while not GPIO.input(b_pin):
        pass
```

I do not understand exactly what it means pass (I do not know is pass is pass or continue the while).
[Thank you for the answer it makes sense but I would like to solve]

[Edit]

Following the issue with the Timer searching I find that I sould use a StopWatch, so changed to the following:

```
    Stopwatch pulseLength;
    public void Charge()
    {

        pulseLength = new Stopwatch();
        pulseLength.Start();
        FirstGpio.SetDriveMode(GpioPinDriveMode.Output);
        SecondGpio.SetDriveMode(GpioPinDriveMode.Input);

        FirstGpio.Write(GpioPinValue.High);

        while(SecondGpio.Read() == GpioPinValue.Low)
        {

        }
        pulseLength.Stop();
        Temperature = pulseLength.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;

    }

    private void Discharge()
    {
        FirstGpio.SetDriveMode(GpioPinDriveMode.Input);
        SecondGpio.SetDriveMode(GpioPinDriveMode.Output);
        SecondGpio.Write(GpioPinValue.Low);
    }

    public async void Initialize()
    {
        Discharge();
        await Task.Delay(100);
        Charge();
        await Task.Delay(100);
        Initialize();
    }
```

Now I have times but are not like so precise like [example](https://thornitsolutions.wordpress.com/2012/07/10/simple-thermometer-using-rc-circuit/)

These are the values I had:

2.6,2.6,1.9,1.9,2.6,2.6,10.6,10.6 really random.

Might be I should use ValueChanged but I tested and the same, Any idea how to get success the time?

Answer (score 1):

In Python pass means do nothing, it's like a NOP (no operation) in assembler.  It's used where the language syntax requires a statement but there is nothing to be done.  You could use dummy = 1 instead.

Is the Recharge function meant to be recursive?  I'd have thought not.

You'll have to experiment to get the timings right.  The code is timing how long it takes to charge a capacitor through a variable resistance.  Depending on your components this might take anywhere between a microsecond and a second.

As I say you will need to experiment.  I have no idea of the timing granularity which can be achieved by Windows IoT or the number of gpio reads which can be  made per second.

Comment: I have updated the question, the suggestions are good to find by myself the answer, I have improved it but not really succesful